# MongoDB - Strange difference in behavior with "contains" queries on arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Collection called test which has the following document stored:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c128451f6e8eb70b846018f"),
"NumericValues" : [ 
    112233, 
    112244
],
"StringValues" : [ 
    "112233", 
    "112244"
]}
```

When I perform a query filtering on StringValues I get a matching record.

This one returns 1 record:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"StringValues":"112233"})
```

However, neither of the following queries returns any records...

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"NumericValues":112233})
db.getCollection('test').find({"NumericValues": { $eq: 112233}})
```

How is that possible?
Why does filtering on arrays of strings work, but not array of numeric values?
(I'm running a MongoDB 3.2.0 in Azure Cosmos)

Comment: I don't have an idea about 3.2 version but its fully working in MongoDB 4.0.
I have checked both of the above queries are working fine.
Probably you need to upgrade to 4.0.

Comment: also you can try this 
db.test.find({"NumericValues": { $in:[ 112233]}})

Comment: We don't have any possibility to upgrade as we are host in Azure Cosmos DB.
Seems like we might be able to go to 3.4, but no further.

Also db.test.find({"NumericValues": { $in:[ 112233]}}) didn't work either